# Prestashop Search only display exactly

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am new to Prestahop 1.6 and I want to change the behaviour of the search form

```
Currently searching '2/05' will return '22/05', '20/5', '2/051'

Desired: '2/05' will return '2/05' ONLY if exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to overrride the find method of search class in override/classes/Search.php , here what i use on my shop :

```
class Search extends SearchCore {

    public static function find($id_lang, $expr, $page_number = 1, $page_size = 1, $order_by = 'position', $order_way = 'desc', $ajax = false, $use_cookie = true, Context $context = null) {
        if (! $context) {
            $context = Context::getContext();
        }
        $db = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_);

        // TODO : smart page management
        if ($page_number < 1) {
            $page_number = 1;
        }
        if ($page_size < 1) {
            $page_size = 1;
        }

        if (! Validate::isOrderBy($order_by) || ! Validate::isOrderWay($order_way)) {
            return false;
        }

        $intersect_array = array();
        $score_array = array();
        $words = Search::extractKeyWords($expr, $id_lang, false, $context->language->iso_code);

        foreach ($words as $key => $word) {            
            if (! empty($word) && strlen($word) >= (int) Configuration::get('PS_SEARCH_MINWORDLEN')) {
                // $sql_param_search = self::getSearchParamFromWord($word);
                $word = str_replace(array(
                    '%',
                    '_'
                ), array(
                    '\\%',
                    '\\_'
                ), $word);
                $start_search = Configuration::get('PS_SEARCH_START') ? '%' : '';
                $end_search = Configuration::get('PS_SEARCH_END') ? '' : '%';

                $sql_param_search = ($word[0] == '-' ? ' \'' . $start_search . pSQL(Tools::substr($word, 1, PS_SEARCH_MAX_WORD_LENGTH)) . $end_search . '\'' : ' \'' . $start_search . pSQL(Tools::substr($word, 0, PS_SEARCH_MAX_WORD_LENGTH)) . $end_search . '\'');
                $intersect_array[] = 'SELECT DISTINCT si.id_product
                    FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'search_word sw
                    LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'search_index si ON sw.id_word = si.id_word
                    WHERE sw.id_lang = ' . (int) $id_lang . '
                        AND sw.id_shop = ' . $context->shop->id . '
                        AND sw.word LIKE ' . $sql_param_search;
                if ($word[0] != '-') $score_array[] = 'sw.word LIKE \'' . $start_search . pSQL(Tools::substr($word, 0, PS_SEARCH_MAX_WORD_LENGTH)) . $end_search . '\'';
            } else {
                unset($words[$key]);
            }
        }

        if (! count($words)) {
            return $ajax ? array() : array(
                'total' => 0,
                'result' => array()
            );
        }

        $score = '';
        if (is_array($score_array) && ! empty($score_array)) {
            $score = ',(
                SELECT SUM(weight)
                FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'search_word sw
                LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'search_index si ON sw.id_word = si.id_word
                WHERE sw.id_lang = ' . (int) $id_lang . '
                    AND sw.id_shop = ' . $context->shop->id . '
                    AND si.id_product = p.id_product
                    AND (' . implode(' OR ', $score_array) . ')
            ) position';
        }

        $sql_groups = '';
        if (Group::isFeatureActive()) {
            $groups = FrontController::getCurrentCustomerGroups();
            $sql_groups = 'AND cg.`id_group` ' . (count($groups) ? 'IN (' . implode(',', $groups) . ')' : '= 1');
        }

        $results = $db->executeS('
        SELECT DISTINCT cp.`id_product`
        FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_product` cp
        ' . (Group::isFeatureActive() ? 'INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_group` cg ON cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`' : '') . '
        INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category` c ON cp.`id_category` = c.`id_category`
        INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product` p ON cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`
        ' . Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p', false) . '
        WHERE c.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`active` = 1
        AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "search")
        AND product_shop.indexed = 1
        ' . $sql_groups, true, false);

        $eligible_products = array();
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $eligible_products[] = $row['id_product'];
        }
        // $eligible_products2 = array();//half OR
        foreach ($intersect_array as $query) {
            $eligible_products2 = array(); // full AND
            foreach ($db->executeS($query, true, false) as $row) {
                $eligible_products2[] = $row['id_product'];
            }

            $eligible_products = array_unique(array_intersect($eligible_products, array_unique($eligible_products2)));
            if (! count($eligible_products)) {
                return $ajax ? array() : array(
                    'total' => 0,
                    'result' => array()
                );
            }
        }

        $product_pool = '';
        foreach ($eligible_products as $id_product) {
            if ($id_product) {
                $product_pool .= (int) $id_product . ',';
            }
        }
        if (empty($product_pool)) {
            return $ajax ? array() : array(
                'total' => 0,
                'result' => array()
            );
        }
        $product_pool = ((strpos($product_pool, ',') === false) ? (' = ' . (int) $product_pool . ' ') : (' IN (' . rtrim($product_pool, ',') . ') '));

        if ($ajax) {
            $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT p.id_product, pl.name pname, cl.name cname,
                        cl.link_rewrite crewrite, pl.link_rewrite prewrite ' . $score . '
                    FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product p
                    INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_lang` pl ON (
                        p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                        AND pl.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $id_lang . Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl') . '
                    )
                    ' . Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p') . '
                    INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_lang` cl ON (
                        product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category`
                        AND cl.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $id_lang . Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl') . '
                    )
                    WHERE p.`id_product` ' . $product_pool . '
                    ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 10';

            return $db->executeS($sql, true, false);
        }

        if (strpos($order_by, '.') > 0) {
            $order_by = explode('.', $order_by);
            $order_by = pSQL($order_by[0]) . '.`' . pSQL($order_by[1]) . '`';
        }
        $alias = '';
        if ($order_by == 'price') {
            $alias = 'product_shop.';
        } elseif (in_array($order_by, array(
            'date_upd',
            'date_add'
        ))) {
            $alias = 'p.';
        }
        $sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity,
                pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`name`,
             image_shop.`id_image` id_image, il.`legend`, m.`name` manufacturer_name ' . $score . ',
                DATEDIFF(
                    p.`date_add`,
                    DATE_SUB(
                        "' . date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00",
                        INTERVAL ' . (Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20) . ' DAY
                    )
                ) > 0 new' . (Combination::isFeatureActive() ? ', product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity, IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.`id_product_attribute`,0) id_product_attribute' : '') . '
                FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product p
                ' . Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p') . '
                INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $id_lang . Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl') . '
                )
                ' . (Combination::isFeatureActive() ? 'LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute_shop` product_attribute_shop FORCE INDEX (id_product)
                    ON (p.`id_product` = product_attribute_shop.`id_product` AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop=' . (int) $context->shop->id . ')' : '') . '
                ' . Product::sqlStock('p', 0) . '
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'manufacturer` m FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) 
                    ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'image_shop` image_shop FORCE INDEX (id_product)
                    ON (image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop=' . (int) $context->shop->id . ')
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'image_lang` il ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $id_lang . ')
                WHERE p.`id_product` ' . $product_pool . '
                GROUP BY product_shop.id_product
                ' . ($order_by ? 'ORDER BY  ' . $alias . $order_by : '') . ($order_way ? ' ' . $order_way : '') . '
                LIMIT ' . (int) (($page_number - 1) * $page_size) . ',' . (int) $page_size;
        $result = $db->executeS($sql, true, false);

        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product p
                ' . Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p') . '
                INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $id_lang . Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl') . '
                )
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'manufacturer` m ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
                WHERE p.`id_product` ' . $product_pool;
        $total = $db->getValue($sql, false);

        if (! $result) {
            $result_properties = false;
        } else {
            $result_properties = Product::getProductsProperties((int) $id_lang, $result);
        }

        return array(
            'total' => $total,
            'result' => $result_properties
        );
    }
}
```